# Weird behavior of external hard drive

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I use an external hard drive which was previously used as internal loaded with Linux Mint and Windows. When I started using it as external I removed all files from OS installations but now I face a strange issue.

Although the hard drive condition is perfect (according to Hard Disk Sentinel at least) when I place it in a USB port it works fine for some time and after a while it freezes and the operation light in its box indicates that the drive is busy all the time.

The only solution at this point is to remove it from the usb port and plug it again. The very weird thing is that when I place it in a computer running Linux Mint it works without any problem! I suspected that this was an issue of Windows but last week I switched from Mint to Ubuntu and now I have the same problem in Ubuntu too.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I guess the proper solution is to back up the drive and format it but I don't have a second one to do this job. Does anyone have an idea of what to check? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the usb controller in the hard drive adapter is flaky.

Comment: Without a backup device this will be difficult to solve.

Comment: @Moab indeed that was the problem. The adapter of the external case was flaky. I tried with a second case and it is working perfectly! Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter of the external case was not working properly. I used the drive in another case and everything works ok.